# Which functions are being used from a header file in C/C++?

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-code, header-files

I am trying to understand a source code (C/C++) that is very lengthy. I was wondering if there is any way to find out which functions are being used from which header file in VS Code? Is there any VS Code extension for it? I have read a similar question posted at the following link.
[What functions are used from an imported header in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269844/what-functions-are-used-from-an-imported-header-in-c)

I don't want to remove #include for every header file and compile it to check which functions go off and repeat this process for every file. Any VS Code extension that enables me to just hover over a function to see its source header file or something similar to this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know such extension, but I am not saying there is none. However, you can always find the desired header and check the functions here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: You can use RMB -> Got To Declaration over a function . It will open the .h file that declares it. It's not as simple as a tooltip but it's better than nothing.

Comment: This is a job for a static analysis tool.  Let it parse your code and pump out reports about what is and is not being used, etc

Comment: just comment out the ones you are not sure about and compile

Comment: I don't have a VS Core extension in mind, but I've recently come across to SourceTrail https://www.sourcetrail.com/ , which seems to be a good tool to get an overview of an entire code base.

It has a feature that enables you to select any function and see which component uses it in a graph.

Comment: Thank you @Onyrew Your link is really helpful. At least now I can get an idea of what kind of functions are being.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on RMB. Is it an extension for VS Code? @RSahu

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you suggest me any static analysis tool for it.

Comment: @rioV8 I feel this is a very tedious task that's why I was looking for something smarter.

Comment: Thank you @PikaPika. This looks interesting. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @MuhammadHassanKhan, the RMB actioni is available in Visual Studio. I see that option in Visual Studio Code but I don't know how to configure it to make that actioin work.

Comment: Why do want to know from which header a functions is included? What for information does it give you in understanding the source? Much better to look for what the function does with cppreference.com. And maybe just commenting will signal intellisence to mark all the functions that it can't find anymore.

Comment: @rioV8 the code I am working on contains a lot of custom created header files created specifically for this code. These header files are not mentioned on any site. That's why I was asking for help.

Comment: @RSahu What option to select from RMB?

Comment: @MuhammadHassanKhan RMB -> "Go To Declaration"

Comment: @RSahu Thank you but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: you can run a doxygen on your source code

Comment: @rioV8 I'll try that. Thank you.